# Drawing things in the right order, Java

Tags: java, graph, paintcomponent

I'm in the process of writing a "Paint" application in Java consisting of rectangular nodes and undirected edges. The problem is that the beginning of the edge is in the center of the rectangle the edge is connected to, and the end of the edge is in the center of the other rectangle this edge is connected to.

To avoid drawing the intersection between the rectangle and the edge, I draw edges first and nodes afterwards, so that they are placed on top of the edges, thus hiding the intersection.

The problem arises when another node, which does not correspond to that edge is placed along the edge. In this scenario, because edges are drawn first, the node appears on top of the edge. However, that is not what I want. I want the edge to show on top of the node.

Images:
 [how it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzVFY.png) and [how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVyUT.png)

The most comprehensive way I can think of to fix this would be to draw nodes first and afterwards draw the edges avoiding the intersections of the edge with the two nodes it is connected to. However that is difficult to do on paper because I draw edges using `drawLine`, and I do not have the possibility to check for intersections.

This is why I draw edges first, but then the problem I mentioned arises. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is only solvable if nodes have something like a priority, then you can draw sorted by priority of the nodes; render the connections of the node first, then render the node. Repeat for follwing node. If there is no such thing as an ordering criterion, there is no single solution that is correct - or rather any solution can be deemed correct.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a solution to problem #1. You need to "move" the edge's endpoints away from the center of the rectangle. That way you won't have to draw the nodes last and automatically solve your question at hand.

My proposed solution in Step 2 only works if the connecting nodes are left and right of each other, otherwise you need slightly more advanced math of which I made a start in Step 2.1.

Step 1: an edge is nothing more than two `Point`s where a `Point` is just an `x` and `y` value. Find the left and right ends of the edge by comparing the `x` of each edge. We'll save this as `xLeft`, `xRight`, `yLeft` and `yRight` for simplicity. Maybe you have something else for this, but you get the idea.

Step 2: move the `xLeft` half the width of the rectangle to the right and subtract half the width of the rectangle from `xRight`.

(Optional) Step 2.1: in case two connecting nodes are above each other, you can use `Math.atan2(yRight-yLeft, xRight-xLeft)` to calculate the angle. If the value is in the lower spectrum (between `-3pi/4` and `-pi/4`) add and subtract half the height of the rectangle on the respective y values. You can fiddle around with this to create the math and logic for all 4 directions if you want.

Step 3: draw the new edges after having drawn the nodes. The edges are now "connected" to the edge(s) of your rectangles.

Feel free to ask questions, although I suggest you try putting this into code first.